# Git history including/interleave submodule commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'd like to get a `git log` for the repository and all submodules. The manpage says that `git log --submodule` should be used but this doesn't work for me.

------- Edit -------

As an example - what I run:

```
git clone git://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Core.git
cd Core
git submodule init && git submodule update
git log --submodule
```

The output of `git log --submodule` doesn't include the commits from any of the submodules anyhow - just the commits where submodule pointers have been changed.

What's missing?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are there actually commits in the submodule to be displayed in the commit range you're running git-log over in the parent repo?

Comment: Did you initialize and update your submodules? (`git subomdules init`/`git submodules update`)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds as though you're expecting `--submodule` to interleave submodule commits with those from the parent repository in the `git log` output, but unfortunately that's not what it does.

The `--submodule` argument defines how submodule differences are shown - so you'll only see its effects if you're using e.g. `git log -p` to show patches for each change. Normally, `git log -p` will just show the hashes for the before and after commits for a submodule change in the patch:

```
$ git log -1 -p
commit 111808a2bb8c9683d3abe68df419759848ddb16e
Author: Simon Whitaker <simon@...>
Date:   Fri Jan 13 10:40:41 2012 +0000

    Updated ObjectiveFlickr ref

diff --git a/submodules/ObjectiveFlickr b/submodules/ObjectiveFlickr
index b37c053..1bede67 160000
--- a/submodules/ObjectiveFlickr
+++ b/submodules/ObjectiveFlickr
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit b37c0539a536147957c01ad01cf2d8666bcbde9e
+Subproject commit 1bede67b8258ed4b95b5d3d6c2175b5e64912269
```

With `--submodule` you get the actual commit message from the submodule listed:

```
$ git log -1 -p --submodule
commit 111808a2bb8c9683d3abe68df419759848ddb16e
Author: Simon Whitaker <simon@...>
Date:   Fri Jan 13 10:40:41 2012 +0000

    Updated ObjectiveFlickr ref

Submodule submodules/ObjectiveFlickr b37c053..1bede67:
  > Set SKIP_INSTALL to YES so that Product > Archive 
  still builds app rather than Xcode archive
```