# git show unpushed work

Tags: git

How can I find out what work is not yet pushed to another repository. In other words; what would I permanently loose if I was to delete that repository?

Currently I use the following 3 lines, but I would like to know if this is a complete cover and if it is a sane approach:

```
git status --short
git log --branches --not --remotes --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --oneline
git stash list
```

update: it seems that submodules are not checked. Is there a way to include submodules recursively?

Comment: those coming here from google, see [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems that submodules are not checked. Is there a way to include submodules recursively?

Not easily, because each submodule can have its own history, set of branches and upstream repo ('origin' or even another name)

As described in "[Git history including/interleave submodule commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8850366/6309)", `git log --submodules` would just indicate the SHA1 currently referenced by the parent repo.

That leaves you with a recursive command like:

```
git submodule foreach git log
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like something like `git show-branch --color=always -a --more=15`?

The `*` is your local repo, the `+` indicates the others. If a comment is present in a repo, the `*`/`+` will indicate it's existence there.

What exists in your `master` branch but not in `origin/master` is not pushed yet.